# what it is equivalent to rpm -qf /path/file ?

Tags: dpkg

rpm -qf give me the name of the package that contains the file for example:

```
rpm -qf /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.18-200.fc26.x86_64
```

kernel-core-4.14.18-200.fc26.x86_64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for `dpkg -S <package name>`.

Example:

```
~$ dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic 
linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
```

Hope this helps!